# How to configure periods dynamically according to number of persons?

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I'm making a database for my expense tracker/splitter (offers possibility to add/edit/remove `Transactions`). Depending on number of `Persons`, when you add a new transaction you must specify who paid and to what amount. Then it creates `Payments` row for each person within `Transactions`.

You must configure each person's salary then it will calculate the pro-rata for each person for unpaid expenses (`IsPayed` flag). Once every person is ready to settle they must create a period (start and end date). All transactions between those dates will be tagged as paid (`IsPayed = true`) and the application will assume they are settle and frozen in time. There will be a FK between `Transaction` and `Period` to specify from which period a transaction was paid.

I want to add a relation between `Period(Id)` and `SalaryConfiguration(IdGroup)`; it would specify `SalaryConfiguration` for said period, but I can't since `IdGroup` is not a primary key. I do not know how a period can be dynamic on the number of persons and specific configurations. How can I link `SalaryConfiguration` and `Periods`?

Database DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "Transactions" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "FkIdCategories"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Date"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Description"   TEXT,
    "Cost"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "IsPayed"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    CONSTRAINT "Fk_Categories_Transactions" FOREIGN KEY("FkIdCategories") REFERENCES "Categories"("Id")
);

CREATE TABLE "Categories" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "Payments" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "FkIdPerson"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "FkIdTransaction"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Amount"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Fk_Persons_Payments" FOREIGN KEY("FkIdPerson") REFERENCES "Persons"("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "Fk_Transactions_Payments" FOREIGN KEY("FkIdTransaction") REFERENCES "Transactions"("Id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "Persons" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "SalaryConfigurations" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "IdGroup"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "FkIdPerson"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Salary"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "SaveDate"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Fk_Persons_SalaryConfiguration" FOREIGN KEY("FkIdPerson") REFERENCES "Persons"("Id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "Periods" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "StartDate" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "EndDate"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "FkIDSalaryConfigurationGroup"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Constraints (including PKs & FKs) need not hold, be known or be declared to record or query. In the relational (& ER) model a table represents a relation/relationship/association & that is how we record & query. "Relation" & "relationship" meaning a FK is an ubiquitous abuse of terminology in methods & presentations that misunderstand the relational model. Constraint declarations are for integrity--they allow a DBMS to reject attempted updates to known invalid states. Time to follow a published academic information modelling & DB design textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the two tables together with  another table that contains `SalaryConfigurations(Id)` and `Periods(Id)`.